# Cant install CPLEX 12.9 on my macOS Catalina

Tags: macos, cplex, macos-catalina

I downloaded the cplex_studio1290-osx file from the IBM website. But can't install, it says that the application can't be opened.

Comment: You might get more responses if you ask at [apple](https://apple.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: You should have a cplex_studio1290-osx.bin file, or something similar. Do `chmod +x cplex_studio1290-osx.bin; ./cplex_studio1290-osx.bin`

Answer (score 0):

let me quote [developerworks](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/topic?id=b99021f2-f498-4f63-abca-ca04c9325af7)

> I got the IDE in CPLEX Optimization Studio 12.9 to work on Catalina
>   using the following steps:
>
> - Download this IBM JDK https://ibm.box.com/s/6nw16tgpe5oxdq52nh7hpldwyzhpsp9v.
> - Expand the tar file. This will create a folder named Contents. Don't rename it.
> - Move that folder to /Applications/CPLEX_Studio129/opl/oplide
> - In the same folder /Applications/CPLEX_Studio129/opl/oplide, right-click on the Oplide app, and choose Show Package Contents
> - Navigate to /Applications/CPLEX_Studio129/opl/oplide/Oplide.app/Contents/Eclipse
>     and open the file oplide.ini with TextEdit.
> - The second line is 
>      /Applications/CPLEX_Studio129/opl/oplide/jre/bin/java    Change it to 
>      /Applications/CPLEX_Studio129/opl/oplide/Contents/Home/bin/java

Comment: I also saw this post, but my problem is I do not have CPLEX 12.9 installed in my laptop. Thanks, anyway.